# Should I use a tuple or list for classifiers in my setup.py?

Tags: python, list, tuples, setup.py

I've got two Python projects. In the `setup.py` of one, my classifiers are inside square brackets:

```
classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Natural Language :: English',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
    'Programming Language :: Python',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
]
```

In the other, they are inside parentheses:

```
classifiers=(
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Natural Language :: English',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
    'Programming Language :: Python',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
)
```

I'm aware that one is a list and the other is a tuple, and I don't see any issue with using either, but I'd like to know, does it matter which format is used?

Comment: Tuples are immutable, lists are mutable.

Comment: if `classifiers` gonna change in your code then there's no point using it as `tuple` if not then it's upto your preference,

Comment: This question is not opinion based, contrary to all the close votes. There is an objective right choice here, which is list. See below.

Comment: Additionally, keep in mind that the question is "does it matter which format is used?". The answer to that is not really opinion based: it either does matter or it doesn't. The fact that it does makes it even less opinon based.

Comment: Yes, I think the fact that we get the warning `Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'` when using a tuple also suggests that it's not opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, making it a tuple was not an option at all:

- https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/2185
- https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/670

While using a tuple is no longer an outright error, you will still get a warning when you run your setup:

```
$ python setup.py sdist
Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
...
```

**TL;DR**

Use a list instead of tuple for your classifiers.